# RegisterActivity: cannot be resolved to a type, AppEngine

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-app-engine

I have set up my computer with windows 8.1 completely new (formatted), to be sure to have a working system.

I have installed Eclipse and the plugins the following way:

1. download and unpack eclipse Kepler
2. install JDK
3. install android SDK
4. install android SDK-plugins in eclipse
5. in android sdk: install all extras, API 19, in tools: Android SDK Tools, Android SDK-Platform Tools, Android SDK Build Tools (only newest, 19.0.3)
6. install all google plugins for kepler(Google App Engine Tools for Android, Google Plugin for eclipse, GWT Designer for GPE, SDKs)

Now, is everything set up correctly, to use google app engine correctly?

When I create a new app engine connected android project, google creates a bugged project. 
I have 50 errors, of which 49 can be resolved by changing the Java version from 1.4 to 1.7 in the app engine project (Properties: Java Compiler and Project Facet)

However in the non-appengine project, in the MainActivity I get following error:
RegisterActivity cannot be resolved to a type.

How to solve this? I did not do anything by myself yet, I only created a project and I already have an error...

Comment: Does the RegisterActivity class exist in the project? In which package ? Is it imported correctly in the MainActivity ?

Comment: No, RegisterActivity was not created.

Comment: So it seems something went wrong during code generation. Do u have JAVA_HOME properly set and pointing to JDK 7 you have ?

Comment: yes, JAVA_HOME, even JRE_HOME and a path to jdk/bin

Answer (score 0):

You are very thorough, which is good.  Your development installation appears to have flaws, and you might be trying to make it run before you have seen it walk.  You need to divide and conquer the potential problems.  Initially simplify what you aim to create.

To pinpoint the errors, try the two standard tutorials before starting on your own design: first build and deploy an [AppEngine project without Android components](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/introduction), and only after that works, build and deploy an [Android to AppEngine project](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/getstarted/clients/android/).  Somewhere along that process your errors will show up, and then you should have a more specific piece of source code to show and discuss in this question.

Comment: Thanks for that advise, I will start doing that tutorial first and when I encounter a bug, I will post here!

Comment: In Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs, the path was set automatically by eclipse itself (or android sdk) to the Java/JRE folder. 
I have installed the Java SDK, not only JRE. 
In the suggested tutorial, when I came to the point, that I add the JSPs, I had to change that path to the Java/jdk_1.8.0 folder in order to avoid an error message. Should it be configured that way? (That does not solve my previous error with RegisterActivity)

Comment: SDK is what you need, and it includes a JRE as well.  However, JDK 1.8.0 is probably too new, it usually takes Google several months to upgrade their dependencies, so you might be better off with a Java 7 SDK (1.7.x).  You might have to download and install an older JDK.  You can have several versions side by side in one computer.

Comment: Edit: my last question answered itself... ;)
Installed JDK 7 now. The tutorial was updated yesterday, I will do that again when I have time (this time it is using maven)

Comment: I completed the Java Tutorial successfully. The Tutorial, which u advised me to do next says that the backend tutrial must be done first, but the backend API is marked as deprecated, so I won't do that. Is the "Mobile Backend Starter"-Tutorial also deprecated? It is not marked as deprecated, but it uses the backend API. I don't know why the backend API is deprecated. Is this only temporarly or is the Modules API a new component which google introduced to replace Backends API? Sorry, this is all new for me ;-)

Comment: Modules will indeed replace Backends, and the deprecation notice is to advise developers to redesign their applications.  The change will improve future AppEngine capabilities.  The tutorials are not quite up to date with this change, but it may take several months for them to be rewritten.  I suggest you follow the deprecated Backends based tutorial in the meantime.  Backends will remain available for long enough.  What you learn will put you in a better position to migrate to Modules later.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday, a new version of Android SDK (22.6.2) was released. Apparently, the problem with RegisterActivity was solved in this update. Now I can create an Appengine connected Android Project without any errors!